# Eclipse AdMob not finding attributes

Tags: android, admob

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.tahakki.buttonpuzzlelite"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
                        <org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView android:id="@+id/flip_render"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="0px"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"                           
                                />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/flip_render"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/flip_render"
        >
<!-- Ad here -->

<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:backgroundColor="#000000"
           app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
           app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
    />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Eclipse tells me that app:backgroundColor, app:primaryTextColor and app:secondaryTextColor cannot be found. I have the appropriate admob JAR in my build path. What's wrong?

Comment: are you sure you imported the library correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had imported the library but not the attrs.xml file.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "importing" the attrs.xml file? I'm having a similar problem and would love to know how to fix it!